# How to return JSON data in a list after retrieving it from a URL source?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My colleague and I are creating a simple directory app for departments and hit a roadblock - we can't successfully post the data from our database after trying to implement the data from our database directly into the app.

We were able to use dummy data for proof of concept and now having a difficult time trying to get the real data to show up. The data is being retrieved and parsed as a JS Object format which should be exactly what we were using before, however we're getting the error of:

```
Line 42:22: 'person' is not defined. no-undef
```

Here's what we have for our code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../scss/App.css';
import PeopleList from './components/PeopleList';
import Accordion from "./components/Accordion";

import "../scss/main.scss";

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <h1>Address Book</h1>
        <PeopleList /> {/*The component we're having issues with */}
        <Accordion addresses={addresses} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

PeopleList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import '../../scss/App.css';

// let person = [
//     {
//         "division": "Town 1",
//         "deptName": "Department 1",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 1",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 2",
//         "deptName": "Department 2",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 2",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 3",
//         "deptName": "Department 3",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 3",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 4",
//         "deptName": "Department 4",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 4",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 5",
//         "deptName": "Department 5",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 5",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 6",
//         "deptName": "Department 6",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 6",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
// ];

class PeopleList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        person: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/phonebook/all'
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data)
            const person = res.data;
            console.log(person)
            const obj = JSON.parse(person);
            console.log(obj)
            this.setState({ person });
        })
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: ''
        }
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <>
            <div className="people-list">

                <ul className="list">
                    {person.map((p)=> {
                        return (
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    {p.name} <br />
                                    {p.title} <br />
                                    {p.phone1} <br />
                                    {p.division}
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default PeopleList
```

With the given axios call, we're under the impression person is being defined as a JS Object class just like our dummy data, but the error message states otherwise. We're successfully able to console.log() the data per the calls during the axios call when we comment out the person.map() part in the return so we know the data is being returned, but not sure what we're missing to have the data be returned on the client side. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look like a JavaScript error, but a linting error. You probably mean to use `this.state.person.map`?

Comment: In render you need to refer to the person in the state.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the constructor and axios call - our data is now returning!!

PeopleList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import '../../scss/App.css';

// let person = [
//     {
//         "division": "Town 1",
//         "deptName": "Department 1",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 1",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 2",
//         "deptName": "Department 2",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 2",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 3",
//         "deptName": "Department 3",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 3",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 4",
//         "deptName": "Department 4",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 4",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 5",
//         "deptName": "Department 5",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 5",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
//     {
//         "division": "Town 6",
//         "deptName": "Department 6",
//         "name": "Pluto",
//         "title": "Title 6",
//         "phone1": "(123) 456-7890",
//     },
// ];

class PeopleList extends React.Component {

    // state = {
    //     person: []
    // }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/phonebook/all'
        })
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({ person:res.data });
        })
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: '',
            person: []
        }
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <>
            <div className="people-list">

                <ul className="list">
                    {this.state.person.map((p)=> {
                        return (
                            <li>
                                <p>
                                    {p.name} <br />
                                    {p.title} <br />
                                    {p.phone1} <br />
                                    {p.division}
                                </p>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default PeopleList
```

Comment: I don't think moving the state was needed

Comment: remember to give each iterated element a unique [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to avoid problems later `return (<li key={p.name}>` (use a unique property of `p`)